# 'no calls to throwing functions occur within 'try' expression [warning] in swift 3

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3, try-catch, warnings

I'm trying to delete an object from core data and I tried it within try catch as below.

```
do {
   try self.managedContext.deleteObject(self.productList[indexPath.row])
} catch let error as NSError {
        print("something wrong with the delete : \(error.userInfo)")
}
```

it say `'no calls to throwing functions occur within 'try' expression` and `'catch block is unreachable because no errors are throw in 'do' block`. following image give you more idea.

[image]

why is this. I have no idea. how to solve this. hope your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `deleteObject` method doesn't throw.  Remove the `Do-Catch` block and the warning will go away.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the method that you are invoking after `try`  **throws**.

Example:

```
func someThrowingFunction() throws -> Int {
    // ...
}

let x = try? someThrowingFunction()

let y: Int?
do {
    y = try someThrowingFunction()
} catch {
    y = nil
}
```

more information about that here: [ErrorHandling](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ErrorHandling.html)